# How can I initialize an optional array?

Tags: swift

I want to initialize my Empty Array with some data, however the array does not accept new data, It must be easy thing, but I do not know what I am missing!

```
var arrayOfString: [String]?

arrayOfString?.append( "New Data"); print( "\(arrayOfString?.count)" )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Initializing* means to assign a default value

```
var arrayOfString: [String]? = []
```

But in almost all cases collection types can be declared (and initialized) non-optional

```
var arrayOfString = [String]()
```

Comment: Or I can use this:  **var arrayOfString: [String]?; arrayOfString = []**

Comment: You could, but every time you use a semicolon, the compiler will eat one of your fingers.